# giving an arraylist the value of another arraylist JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist, set

I'm trying to do the following with Java, is this allowed?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Apple {
    void makeAppleArrayList() {
        ArrayList<String> appleArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        appleArrayList.add("apple"); 
        Banana b = new Banana();
        b.copyAppleArrayList(appleArrayList);
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
class Banana {
    ArrayList<String> bananaArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    void copyAppleArrayList(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        bananaArrayList = arrayList; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try it. Although Banana will just have a reference to Apple's ArrayList in your example. Once you fix your compiler error of course. Have you considered `addAll`?

Comment: my bad about insert, just noticed

Comment: no, i forgot about that, maybe i should try it, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well instead of making an instance of banana in apple why dont you make an instance of apple in banana and just do this:

```
Apple apple = new Apple();
bananaArrayList = apple.appleArrayList;
```

So since it is created inside a function you initialize it in the constructor like so:

```
public class Apple{
public ArrayList<Perk> appleArrayList;

public PerkGenerator() {
        this.appleArrayList = new ArrayList();
```

And if you do that, there is no need to do it inside a function. But if you still want to do it inside a function. Just keep that code. And do this inside apple:

```
public ArrayList makeApple(){
    ArrayList apples = new ArrayList();
    return apples;
```

And then inside of banana you do this:

```
bananaArrayList = apple.makeApple
```

This works, because the make apple function returns an arraylist :)
Here is some info on returning values from methods :)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Hope i could help :)

Comment: :) Anytime Glad to help out

Comment: i just noticed, in apple, the applearraylist is declared within the method, can it still be called like you showed?

Comment: As long as you initialize it outside of that method in your constructor. Yes it certainly can. :)

Comment: so you mean i need to create a constructor and declare it in that? (sorry im kind of new to all this)

Comment: Thats ok :) Ill add it to my answer give me a second :)

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! very helpful, im learning new things :)

Comment: Glad i could help :) We all were new to this once :) A lot of people on this website dont seem to remember that :)